# Do you have to say anything to activate a NerveGear?

Tags: sword-art-online

I was wondering if you had to say anything to activate a NerveGear. I remember Kirito saying something before he went into the SAO world but I can't remember what. I thought he might have said something to activate the NerveGear, but I don't know if he actually did or if my memory is playing tricks on me. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: [linku starto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWFHvp03ne0)

Answer (score 14):

> To use the NerveGear, the player wears the game console over the head. Then it is recommended for the player to find a comfortable position to station the body, commonly a bed. Afterwards, **the game will load upon utterance of the initiation words, "Link Start".**

(Emphasis mine)

[Source](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/NerveGear#Usage).

Answer (score 1):

The first time Kirito dove into the SAO world, he did say something like "link start" but it has nothing to do with it. Afterwards, when he dove into ALfeheim, he did not utter anything, so that was just a way for the anime developer to make that scene cool.

In *Accel world* (another anime, partially similar to SAO), players have to shout "link burst" to get into the gaming world.

Comment: To make it more relevant, it might be worth mentioning that both SAO and Accel World are stories from the same person, Reki Kawahara.